# Key to Different Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have a `log` table like this that saves all logs for all of my table in my MySQL database:

```
+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
| LogID | LogTypeID | LogDateTime | ReferenceID | TableName | UserID |
+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
|     1 |         1 |  2012-10... |           1 |    client |      1 |
|     2 |         1 |  2012-10... |           1 |      plan |      1 |
|   ... |       ... |         ... |         ... |       ... |    ... |
+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-----------+--------+
```

The `log` table saves all the logs when I *Insert*, *Update*, or *Delete* to my tables in my database which is identified by my `LogTypeID` column. The `ReferenceID` column is the *Primary Key* of the table identified in my `TableName` column, all my Primay Keys has the same type of `int(10)` and it is same for the `ReferenceID` column.

I always use my `log` table for identifying when this data was inserted so I cannot clear the logs.

**I have no problem on it at first, but now my queries are becoming slow when using the `log` table because of many data.** I [try to improve the performance of my database server](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/) and it become a little faster than before, but still it is slow. Most of my queries `INNER JOIN` to the `log` table.

I was thinking of adding a *Foreign Key* to my `ReferenceID` to all the tables that uses the `log` table because I think Keys may improve the performance of my queries, but I'm not sure if it is feasible.

Can I make my `ReferenceID` column a foreign key to all my tables?

My database server is MySQL Server 5.5.25, my tables are all InnoDB.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN EXTENDED results here. It is the first thing that we need to see for performance check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly and `ReferenceID` holds different table `PRIMARY KEY` values, you will not be able to define it as a `FOREIGN KEY`, since a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint is only able to reference a single table and cannot switch based on other column values.

Instead, you can create an index on each of `ReferenceID` and `TableName`, or perhaps even a composite index across both of them:

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_referenceid` ON `log` (`ReferenceID`);
CREATE INDEX `idx_tablename` ON `log` (`TableName`);
```

Or as a composite index across both columns, assuming you always need both to query against `log`.

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_referenceid_tablename` ON `log` (`ReferenceID`,`TableName`);
```

Comment: Yes. A foreign key constraint would create an index as well, but your table structure won't allow for that. So you can attempt to index the columns individually and as a pair.

Comment: It really does! From `15.0s` to `0.6s`. Thank you very much!